# ExceptionHandler No metadata for "Profile" was found in nest.js

Tags: nestjs

I was creating Nest.js project and faced some problems with it. I assume the problem lies within  profile.entity.ts file since if I remove that file then all works ok. So, I have several files app.module.ts file:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { typeOrmConfig } from './config/typeorm.config';
import { ProfileModule } from './profile/profile.module';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig), ProfileModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

profile.entity.ts

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Profile extends BaseEntity{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    @Column()
    fullName: string;
    @Column()
    company: string;
    @Column()
    position: string;
    @Column()
    dateOfBirth: Date;
    @Column()
    phoneNumber: string;
    @Column()
    additionalPhoneNumber: string;
    @Column()
    email: string;
    @Column()
    additionalEmail: string;
    @Column()
    website: string;
    @Column()
    additionalWebsite: string;
    @Column()
    facebook: string;
    @Column()
    instagram: string;
    @Column()
    telegram: string;
    @Column()
    whatsapp: string;
    @Column()
    vk: string;
    @Column()
    tikTok: string;
    @Column()
    linkedIn: string;
    @Column()
    youTube: string;
    @Column()
    skype: string;
    @Column()
    modeDetails: string;

}
```

profile.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ProfileController } from './profile.controller';
import { ProfileRepository } from './profile.repository';
import { ProfileService } from './profile.service';

@Module({
  imports:[TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ProfileRepository])],
  controllers: [ProfileController],
  providers: [ProfileService]
})
export class ProfileModule {}
```

profile.repository.ts

```
import { Profile } from './profile.entity';
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';

@EntityRepository(Profile)
export class ProfileRepository extends Repository<Profile> {}
```

typeorm.config.ts

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

export const typeOrmConfig:TypeOrmModuleOptions={
    type:'postgres',
    host:'localhost',
    port:5432,
    username:'postgres',
    password:'M',
    database: 'profileManagement',
    entities:[__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.ts'],
    synchronize:true
}
```

Please help I cannot find the exact place where I did wrong

Comment: Does your `typeOrmConfig` include an `entities` property, and if se can you share it?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, hey Hey), ok I have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `entities` from `__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.ts'` to `__dirname + '/../**/*.entity.js'`. What's happening is that when you transpile the code from ts to js the code moves from `src` to `dist`. At this time, there is no `ts` code in the `dist`, so the glob you're using doesn't find anything. If you use `.js` however, it will find matching files, and be able to make use of the metadata that is set there.